# Ckeditor4 and vuejs2 add extraplugin html5video

Tags: vuejs2, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor4-vue plugin as rich text editor.

here is my code

```
import CKEditor from 'ckeditor4-vue';

window.ckeditor = CKEditor.component;

Vue.component('ckeditor', window.ckeditor).default;

CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'html5video', 'https://raw.githack.com/bahriddin/ckeditor-html5-video/master/html5video/plugin.js' );
```

Getting an error like

```
CKEDITOR is not defined
```

However codepen link is working fine.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/B-L-Praveen/pen/ZEPyVrd)

How can I add extraplugin to the `ckeditor4-vue`?